# Can google amp work with vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, amp-html

Exploring [google amp project](https://www.ampproject.org/) brings me to question, can it work with Vue.js and similar frameworks as it first loads the

```
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
```

and then the style which determines where elements are ment to be in layout before they are actually loaded?

```
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
```

How can this style know about elements which are rendered with Vue.js for example? What is loaded first?

Vue.js in a

```
<div id="app">
  // Some content
</div>
```

or amp as shown above?

Comment: "Can google amp work with vue.js?" — No

Comment: Why is this the case? Is there any workarround for this?

Comment: See the duplicate question.